# Combobox dropdown not displaying special characters

Tags: .net, fonts, combobox, font-face, truetype

[Odd Combobox Behaviour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lblGX.png) I populate the items in a Combobox with city names containing special characters. In the dropdown list they do not display properly, but when I select one, it does display correctly

UPDATE 4:
It is an odd font issue with the ComboBox (see comments)

ORIGINAL POST:

This is how I populate the Combobox from an XML file:

```
Public Shared Sub PopulateCities()
    Dim strPath As String = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(
        System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase)
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim i As Integer
    ds.InferXmlSchema(Strings.Mid(strPath, 7) + "/cities.xml", Nothing)
    ds.ReadXml(Strings.Mid(strPath, 7) + "/cities.xml")
    If ds.Tables.Count > 0 Then
        Dim a As String
        For i = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
            a = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item("NOME")
            MainForm.LocationBox.Items.Add(a)
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

The items in the list must display the same way as the current item in the Combobox.

UPDATE:

When switching to a system font, the problem does not appear, but I need to use my own font.
[ComboBox using System Font](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7hR49.png)

The font is assigned programmatically this way:

```
  Public Shared pfc As PrivateFontCollection = New PrivateFontCollection()
  Dim strPath As String = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(
            System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase)
  REM Loading Font files
        pfc.AddFontFile(Strings.Mid(strPath, 7) & "\magickfont.ttf")

  SetMagickFont(LocationBox)

  Public Sub SetMagickFont(obj As Object)
        Dim s As Single = obj.font.size
        Dim fs As FontStyle = obj.font.style
        obj.font = New Font(pfc.Families(0), s, fs)
        obj.invalidate
    End Sub
```

UPDATE 2:

Keeping my font, and adding

```
MainForm.LocationBox.Items.Add("Zürich åäö")
```

Gets to the same odd result.
[Manually adding an item to ComboBox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQYPL.png)

Comment: Seems odd. I can see that you are not using the default font. Could you try to switch to the default font to test if the issue is the same when using the default font?

Comment: Also, have you tried putting a break point at the line `MainForm.LocationBox.Items.Add(a)` and debugged to see what the variable `a`contains in the debugger for a city whose name contains special characters.

Comment: The variable contains the correct value, the font does display the special characters, when I select "Z rich" for example, it puts "Zürich" in the box, and that's the odd part.

Comment: I can see that your font works for selected text in your our example, however I suggested trying the default font just to "completely" rule out that it is not some weird font issue :)

Comment: Also, you could try to alter the code to add an item with the special characters as a hard coded string in your program (e.g. `MainForm.LocationBox.Items.Add("Zürich åäö")` ) to see if it makes any difference. It might be an issue with the encoding of your xml file.

Comment: morthb: yes, it seems to be a weird font issue, but I need to use my own font. See picture 2

Comment: I tried also the MainForm.LocationBox.Items.Add("Zürich åäö"), on the third picture you see the result, which is the same odd one.

Comment: Are you using the standard winforms combobox? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.combobox?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: mortb: yes, standard Winform combobox. The only thing added is the change of font, as described by the above sub SetMagickFont.

Comment: Is the font downloadable somewhere?

Comment: ....and do you have the setup of the ComboBox somewhere? (Values from properties window for example)

Comment: mortb: in the form.designer:
  '
        'LocationBox
        '
        Me.LocationBox.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 14.25!, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, CType(0, Byte))
        Me.LocationBox.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.SaddleBrown
        Me.LocationBox.FormattingEnabled = True
        Me.LocationBox.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(21, 186)
        Me.LocationBox.Name = "LocationBox"
        Me.LocationBox.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(268, 32)
        Me.LocationBox.TabIndex = 32

Comment: mortb: The font file upload link died somehow, the new URL is this one: https://jmp.sh/jzlSRRI

Comment: I've tried the font and replicated the issue. (You may unshare the file). When taking a closer look at the selected item, the ü in Zürich is not in the same font it looks more generic (arial?). I'm no expert on fonts, but to me it seems to be a font issue, the characters you need seem not to be present in the font.

Comment: To me it seems the solution would be either to change the font to another font, edit the font file or replace the special characters with the closest lookalikes e.g. ü => u. Not ideal, but the issue doesn't really seem to be a code issue. I've added font tags to your question if someone who knows fonts could provide more information

Comment: @mortb  thank you for your help, at least I nailed down the cause of this odd issue, being the font file and its handling in different parts of the same control.

Comment: Is there a way to "Intercept" the graphical rendering of the ComboBox to make it behave in the right way?  I also have other names in that list such as "São Paulo" or "Asunción" which generate the same odd issue...

Comment: Yes you can override the rendering. I'm no expert at that. Here is a start, but not many details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.comboboxrenderer?view=netframework-4.7.2
I speculate that writing the override might be complicated. I guess you would want the override to insert ¨ or ~ above the characters?

Comment: It might be easier to just edit the font? Here is a free font editor http://fontforge.github.io/en-US/downloads/windows-dl/ There are other editors as well. Of course you need to make sure you have the rights to do so; you need to find out if  are there any copyrights on the font or if it is open source. The font you shared contains just the first 127 characters in unicode + one extra (I loaded it into the editor), so of course there is work to be done. Western language characters are up to unicode 255. After that is eastern european and greek.

Comment: @mortb: just to make the ComboBox react to the font in the same way in the selected item and in the dropdown list.